# Find $f^{-1}$ if a function satisfy only one given statement

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $f$ be a injective function with the domain $\{a,b,c\}$ and range $\{1,2,3\} $ such that exactly one of the following  statement is correct and remaining two are false: $f(a)=1,f(b)\ne 1,f(c)\ne 2$.The value of $f^{-1} $ is

My work

If $f(a)=1$ is true then $f(b)\ne 1$ must be true and $f(c)\ne 2$ may be true. 
This implies the $f(a)=1$ is one of the false statement.

If $f(b)\ne 1 $ is true then $f(a)=2 \space \text{or} \space3$ ,$f(b)=2\space \text{or} \space 3$,and $f(c)=1\space\text{or} \space 2 \space \text{or} \space3$ ,

If $f(c)\ne 2 $ is true then $f(a)=3$ ,$f(b)=2 $,and $f(c)=1$

I don't know how to conclude another false statement from this.

Comment: Disregard that last comment, I follow you now, but I don't think you need the  "and $f(c) \not = 2$ may be true" part to get your first conclusion.

Comment: @DisplayName Yes , I just wrote just possibility.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that one of the statements is true and the other three are false means that we land in one of the following three cases:

- **Case 1.** $f(a) = 1$, $f(b) = 1$ and $f(c) = 2$. This is impossible since $f$ is injective.
- **Case 2.** $f(a) \ne 1$, $f(b) \ne 1$ and $f(c) = 2$. This is impossible, since the requirement that $f(c)=2$ forces either $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ to be equal to $1$.
- **Case 3.** $f(a) \ne 1$, $f(b) = 1$ and $f(c) \ne 2$. This is possible: let $f(a)=2$, $f(b)=1$ and $f(c)=3$. Moreover, this is the only thing $f$ can be in this case, since the requirement that $f(c) \ne 2$ forces $f(c)=3$ and thus $f(a)=2$, by injectivity.

So your function must be the one defined in Case 3.

Comment: Great approach !